# vscode How to change `package scripts` to` launch debug`?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

> package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node -r dotenv/config index.js dotenv_config_path=.env",
```

> .vscode\launch.json

```
{
    //  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "debug",
            "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\index.js",
            "args": ["-r dotenv/config index.js dotenv_config_path=.env"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to debug, but he can't work, How do I configure `launch.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check `Add Configuration` button on lower right corner of `launch.json`.

Sample `npm task` configuration generated from same:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch via NPM",
    "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "run-script",
        "debug"
    ],
    "port": 9229
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: Generating new debug/launch configuration]

Adding additional configuration:
[image: Adding additional options to generated config]

Comment: Where is `node -r dotenv / config index.js dotenv_config_path = .env` written?

Comment: Similar to the configuration in the question. VSCode is quite intuitive, you will get automatic suggestions to add the additional config. Adding new image to my answer for your reference.